# Configure spring boot endpoint for AWS SNS

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I try to  connect my web application (spring boot) with  AWS SNS using http endpoint. When I  contact my endpoint to create a new subscription (sns -> web application) always I got

```
com.amazonaws.services.sns.model.InvalidParameterException: 
Invalid parameter: TopicArn (Service: AmazonSNS; Status 
Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameter; 
Request ID: 151fe19b-c8e3-55ee-ba38-bab3e65af5e9; Proxy: null)
```

Answer (score 1):

To create a **Spring BOOT app** that invokes AWS SNS and has subscription and publish functionality, use the **AWS SDK for Java v2**. See this topic in the ***AWS SNS DEV*** Guide. This example shows both Sync and Java Async examples.

[Build a publish and subscription application that translates messages](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/example_cross_SnsPublishSubscription_section.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the errors that occur during FAIL when sending push messages using AWS SDK

`com.amazonaws.services.sns.model.InvalidParameterException: Invalid parameter: TopicArn (Service: AmazonSNS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameter; Request ID: 151fe19b-c8e3-55ee-ba38-bab3e65af5e9; Proxy: null)`

Error that occurs when a token does not exist or if the token value is incorrect

Comment: you mean when my web application try to respond sns by the confirmation?